Dataset Imbalanced without oversampling
I want to train a YOLO model, but my dataset is imbalanced. Unfortunately, I can't perform oversampling or undersampling, and I also don't want to manipulate the weights or generate synthetic data. Is there a way to balance my model without these methods?
This can be achieved by ensuring that the model gives balanced results for examples with few data points.
